# Submit method by enter key?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to submit a method when the user hits the ENTER key inside a editText field.

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true" 
 />
```

Atm this results in going to the next UI element on screen if the user hits done.
But i'd like to fake-submit a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an `OnEditorActionListener` on your `EditText`. Here's an example:

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            submitButton.performClick();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```